# Calculate Change Without If/While/For Statement or any data structures

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that generates the minimum amount of change (quarters, nickels, dimes, pennies), but with the stipulation that I can't use any kind of if, for, while statements.

I'm sure this is possible, but I'm extremely limited, and can't seem to figure out how to make this work without breaking the rules.

The following code works, accept when it runs into a value of 0, and then it breaks while trying to use the modulus on 0 ( I think):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int cents;

    std::cout << "Enter an amount in cents less than a dollar:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> cents;

    int quarters = cents/25;
    int remainder = cents % (quarters*25);
    int dimes = remainder/10;
    remainder = remainder % (dimes*10);
    int nickels = remainder/5;
    remainder = remainder % (nickels*5);
    int pennies = remainder/1;

    std::cout << "Your change will be: " << "\n Q: " << quarters << "\n D: " << dimes << "\n N: " << nickels << "\n P: " << pennies;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "breaks". Does it seg-fault? Print out an unexpected value (what value)? Wipe your hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
    remainder = remainder % (dimes*10);
```

You allow remainder to become 0. That will cause division by zero here:

```
    int nickels = remainder/5; //0
    remainder = remainder % (nickels*5); // modulo 0 % 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without multiplying each coin by its number of occurrences.  (The modulus does what you're trying to do naturally anyways.)

```
int quarters = cents/25;
int remainder = cents % 25;
int dimes = remainder/10;
remainder = remainder % 10;
int nickels = remainder/5;
remainder = remainder % 5;
int pennies = remainder/1;
```

This way, you will not be using modulus on the number 0 in any situation.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without using `if` you can to shrink `cents` by the found coins and continue from there.  For example:

```
int quarters = cents / 25;
cents -= quarters * 25;
```

Continue like that.